# How to make a carousel scroll vertically?

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I make a carousel scroll vertically on the page?

I don't mean it's items, I mean the whole carousel.

For example, this simple code is a carousel which won't scroll:

```
    var carousel = new Ext.Carousel({
        flex: 1,
        indicator: false,
        dockedItems: [Toolbar],
        layout: 'card',
        defaults: {
            scroll: 'vertical'
        },
        items: [
            {
                html: 'Card 1'
            },
            {
                html: 'Card 2'
            },
            {
                html: 'Card 3'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want exactly ? when the users makes a vertical swipe, what's the behaviour that you expect, scrolling or next item ? if you want the whole caroussel to move consider putting it in a panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the `direction` attribute:

```
var carousel = new Ext.Carousel({
    flex: 1,
    indicator: false,
    dockedItems: [Toolbar],
    layout: 'card',
    direction: 'vertical',
    defaults: {
        scroll: 'vertical'
    },
    items: [
        {
            html: 'Card 1'
        },
        {
            html: 'Card 2'
        },
        {
            html: 'Card 3'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Tried that just now and it doesn't work, carousel is exactly the same.

Comment: Try taking off the `defaults` object.

Comment: That alters the direction of the scrollable carousel items from horizontal to vertical. I want to be able to scroll the entire carousel upwards, I'm not referring to it's items. Thanks for trying though.